# rails devise user management, do I have to do it on all views individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have setup devise and as advised in http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles-devise-rails_admin-cancancan/ I have added a superuser and superviser role.  Now I want to only allow superusers to access a lot of the views (which do CRUD on configuration data).

I know I can do it by wrapping a if around the content.

```
 <% if current_user.superadmin_role? %>
    ...all the content...
 <% else %>
    This page is not available to you
 <% end %>
```

From what I gather I need to do this for all views I want to restrict. But was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it. I.e. can I do something like put all the checks in one place and only allow certain pages through or even disallow all pages and have some code I can put on the public ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If contents you don't want to display is entire page, you can do this by adding
`before_action :authenticate_admin!`
at controller.

```
#some_controller.rb
before_action :authenticate_admin!

def action
  ...
end

private
def authenticate_admin
  unless current_user.superadmin_role?
    redirect_to "403.html"
  end
end
```

Or, if you want to do it non-controller level,

```
#view
<div class="hide <%= 'admin' if @is_admin %>">
  hogehoge
</div>

#controller
before_action set_is_admin
def set_is_admin
  @is_admin = current_user.superadmin_role? ? true : false
end
```

then add

```
# application.css
<style>
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.admin{
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, works but I am getting a 'Corrupted Content Error' if the user is not in superadmin_role.  I guess its the 'redirect_to "403.html"'.  I changed '403.html' to '/' and it now sends user back to the home page.   I Also had to change ':authenticate_admin!' to ':authenticate_admin' to get it working.